# Row-wise concatenate a list of jagged arrays in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, concatenation

I'd like help* in creating a method or (linq) expression that can row-wise concatenate lists (of varying lengths) of jagged arrays as the one below:

```
List<double[][]> orgArrayList = new List<double[][]>();

double[][] one = {
new [] {5d, 6},
new [] {7d, 9}};

double [][] two =  {
new [] {5d, 6},
new [] {7d, 9}};

double [][] three= {
new [] {5d, 6},
new [] {7d, 9}};

orgArrayList.AddRange(new[] {one, two, three});
```

So that the resulting array will be equal to this one:

```
double[][] expected = {
new [] {5d, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6},
new [] {7d, 9, 7, 9, 7, 9}};
```

The number of jagged arrays in my input list(s) will be >=1. All arrays within a single list will be jagged with 2 dimensions, but none of the 2 dimensions will have a fixed/known length (size).

*'help' being a euphemism for someone telling me how to do it

Comment: Try this strategy: Convert arrays to lists, consolidate with AddRange, convert back to arrays.

Comment: Would the down-voter please be so kind and help me improve on my "question-posting-skills', thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with something like this, which appends the elements of each row of `add[]` to the rows of `src[]`, producing a new 2-dimensional array:

```
public static double[][] AppendToRows(double[][] src, double[][] add)
{
    // Allocate new array to hold elements from src[] and add[]
    double[][] res = new double[src.Length][];

    // Append elements to each row of res[]
    for (int i = 0;  i < src.Length;  i++)
    {
        // Allocate row res[i] large enough to hold elements from src[i] and add[i]
        res[i] = new double[src[i].Length + add[i].Length];

        // Copy/append elements from src[i] to res[i]
        int ri = 0;
        for (int j = 0;  j < src[i].Length;  j++)
            res[i][ri++] = src[i][j];

        // Copy/append elements from add[i] to res[i]
        if (i >= add.Length)
            continue;
        for (int j = 0;  j < add[i].Length;  j++)
            res[i][ri++] = add[i][j];
    }
    return res;
}
```

To append multiple arrays together, just call this method multiple times, once for each additional array that needs to be concatenated onto the resulting array.

A more comprehensive solution would be to take a `List<double[][]>` of input arrays, and to loop through each array in the list as you build each row of the result. But I have left that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Cheers @David; Creating a method for two arrays and then looping through the list using that method seems pretty straight forward... once one recognizes it as a possibility :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension, that will concatenate arrays the way you need, so it will looks like Linq:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static T[][] ConcatArrays<T>(this T[][] array, T[][] concatWith)
    {

        var max = Math.Max(array.Length, concatWith.Length);
        var result = new T[max][];
        for (var index = 0; index < max; index++)
        {
            var list = new List<T>();
            if (index < array.Length)
            {
                list.AddRange(array[index]);                   
            }

            if (index < concatWith.Length)
            {
                list.AddRange(concatWith[index]);
            }

            result[index] = list.ToArray();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

So the usage of this is:

```
var expected = one.ConcatArrays(two).ConcatArrays(three);
```

Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

As a final solution for my use case I simply combined David's and Valdimir's answer into a **single method that can handle lists of varying lengths (>=1)**.

```
// ========================================
// My interpretation of David's suggestion
// using Valdimir's solution as a basis
// ========================================
public static double[][] RowWiseConcatListedJaggedArrays(List<double[][]> listOfJaggedArray)
{
    var resArray = listOfJaggedArray[0];

    for (int rInd = 1; rInd < listOfJaggedArray.Count; rInd++)
    {
        resArray = resArray.ConcatArrays(listOfJaggedArray[rInd]);
    }

    return resArray;
}
```

And putting everything together...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace RowWiseConcat
{
    public static class Extension
    {
        // ====================
        // Vladimir's solution
        // ====================
        public static T[][] ConcatArrays<T>(this T[][] array, T[][] concatWith)
        {

            var max = Math.Max(array.Length, concatWith.Length);
            var result = new T[max][];
            for (var index = 0; index < max; index++)
            {
                var list = new List<T>();
                if (index < array.Length)
                {
                    list.AddRange(array[index]);
                }

                if (index < concatWith.Length)
                {
                    list.AddRange(concatWith[index]);
                }

                result[index] = list.ToArray();
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        // ========================================
        // My interpretation of David's suggestion
        // using Valdimir's solution as a basis
        // ========================================
        public static double[][] RowWiseConcatListedJaggedArrays(List<double[][]> listOfJaggedArray)
        {
            var resArray = listOfJaggedArray[0];

            for (int rInd = 1; rInd < listOfJaggedArray.Count; rInd++)
            {
                resArray = resArray.ConcatArrays(listOfJaggedArray[rInd]);
            }

            return resArray;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // ... do something that results in orgArrayList, e.g.
            double[][] one =
            {
                new[] {5d, 6},
                new[] {7d, 9}
            };
            double[][] two =
            {
                new[] {5d, 6},
                new[] {7d, 9}
            };
            double[][] three =
            {
                new[] {5d, 6},
                new[] {7d, 9}
            };

            List<double[][]> orgArrayList = new List<double[][]>()
                { one, two, three};

            // Concat list items
            var resArray = RowWiseConcatListedJaggedArrays(orgArrayList);

            // ... continue with resArray
        }
    }
}
```